# Where to add precompile in deploy.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Where would I put the precompile info in my deploy.rb file.  What do I need to change to get this working?  I am able to get my app to run using

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Precompile info

```
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:precompile"

    namespace :deploy do

      desc "Compile assets"
      task :precompile, :roles => :app do
        run "cd #{release_path} && rake RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} assets:precompile"
      end

     end
```

My deploy.rb

```
    # The name of your app
set :application, "sample_app"

# The directory on the EC2 node that will be deployed to
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"

set :keep_releases, 3

# deploy with git
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "git@github.com:username/sample_app.git"
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :branch, "master"
set :use_sudo, true

# gets ssh info
set :user, "ubuntu"
ssh_options[:keys] = ["/Users/User/Documents/ServerKeys/key.pem"]
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
default_run_options[:pty] = true

# The address of the remote host on EC2 (the Public DNS address)
set :location, "0.0.0.0"

# setup some Capistrano roles
role :app, location
role :web, location
role :db,  location, :primary => true

after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_db'

namespace :deploy do

desc "Restart Application"
task :restart, :roles => :app do
  run "touch #{deploy_to}/#{shared_dir}/tmp/restart.txt"
end

desc "Symlinks the database.yml"
task :symlink_db, :roles => :app do
  run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml
  #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capistrano (v2.8.0 and above) includes a recipe to handle this in deployment. Add the following line to Capfile:

```
load 'deploy/assets'
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets